# What kind of traditional IRA should I use to hold funds from old employer 401K plans?

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira, retirement, recommendation

Further to another question I asked , if I am going to open a traditional IRA to hold funds consolidated from old 401K plans, what should I be looking at for the most flexibility? There are lots of banks and companies that offer them. Are some better than others, ex: is Fidelity any good? I don't want to make a mistake and have to transfer my money again after!

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Magazines like SmartMoney often have an annual issue that reviews brokers. One broker may have a wider variety of no-fee mutual funds, and if that's your priority, then the stock commissions may be a moot issue for you. In general, you can't go wrong with a Fidelity or Schwab, and to choose investments within the accounts with an eye toward low expenses.